# c++ "class" doesnt name a type

Tags: c++

i have a bit of a problem but not sure what it is.

header.h:

```
#ifndef CONTINENT_H_INCLUDED
#define CONTINENT_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Territory;
class Player;

namespace Sep
{

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Continent class
  // class consist of many territories 
  //
  class Continent
  {
    private: 

    public:

      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Constructor
      //
      Continent();


      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Copy Constructor
      // Makes a copy of another Continent Object.
      // @param original Original to copy.
      //
      Continent(const Continent& original);


      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Assignment Operator
      // Used to assign one Continent to another
      // @param original Original with values to copy.
      //
      Continent& operator= (Continent const& original);


      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Destructor
      //
 INCLUDED

 virtual ~Continent();

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Constructor to forward attributes
  //
  Continent(std::string name, std::vector<Territory*> territories);

  };
}

#endif  // CONTINENT_H_INCLUDED
```

.cpp:

```
#include "Continent.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Continent::Continent()
{

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Continent::Continent(std::string name, std::vector<Territory*> territories) : 
                name_(name), territories_(territories)
{

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Continent::~Continent()
{

}
```

Sorry for putting in the whole code but i dont want to take any risks. 
ERROR:
g++ -Wall -g -c -o Continent.o Continent.cpp -MMD -MF ./Continent.o.d
Continent.cpp:13:1: error: ‘Continent’ does not name a type

from that i got that it is a problem between the header define and the .cpp but whats the problem there i cant see it.

thx for any help :)

Comment: You put it into a `namespace` for a reason, no? `Sep::Continent::Continent()`

Comment: What is that stray `INCLUDED` doing there above the destructor? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `Continent` in the namespace `Sep` in your header, but in your .cpp, you use `Continent` in global scope, where it is not defined.

You should either add `using namespace Sep;` after the `#include` in your .cpp, wrap all the definitions in a `namespace Sep { ... }`, or put `Sep::` in front of each use of `Continent`.

Comment: No, don't do `using namespace Sep;` if you want to avoid all those `Sep::`'s; instead just wrap all the definitions in a `namespace Sep` context.